# Unity3D - How to have a ui element positioned based off image

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity3D i have an background image with preserve aspect ratio ticked, However when i add unity UI elements such as buttons when i change the aspect ratio the buttons don't stay where they were in the first fist aspect ratio please take a look at the images and sorry if i didn't word the question properly.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For Anyone Who Still Has This Problem**
Try putting anchor points around the actual UI element (This is a custom anchor point so its not in the pre-sets.) as this worked for me!